# How do inherited static properties on a javascript class behave?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading this [article](https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods) on static properties in classes and how a child class inherits the static properties of its parent class. Using this example:

1. Can I firstly confirm that ChromeDevTools isn't updated to show inherited static properties because it doesn't show that `color` is a property on `Dog`?

```js
class Animal {
  static color = "red";
}

class Dog extends Animal {
}

console.log(Animal.color) //"red"
console.log(Dog.color) //"red"
```

2. Can I confirm what's basically happening with inherited static properties: `Dog.color` references a copy of the value of `Animal.color`. And if `Animal.color` were an object, `Dog.color` would make a copy of the address in memory and 'point' back to `Animal.color`?

Comment: Should it be `class Dog extends Animal`?

Comment: Wouldn't #2 be trivially easy to test yourself?

Comment: Inherited properties come from the prototype chain. When you log an object it normally only shows the own properties, not all the properties inherited from prototypes.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Yeah well I just wanted to make sure that's all what was happening because like I say, ChromeDevTools doesn't actually show that `color` is a property of `Dog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a reference to the original property.
It's an independent static property on the child class as if you had defined it on the child class itself.

This means that if you change the static value on one class in the inheritance chain it doesn't change it on the child/parent class.
The only moment they are the same is when the values aren't changed during the runtime.

See the example below.

```js
class Animal {
  static color = "red";
}

class Dog extends Animal {
}
// Both are red, the default value. 
console.log(Animal.color, Dog.color);
Dog.color = 'green';
// Animal remains red, its default value.
console.log(Animal.color, Dog.color);
// Dog remains green, the assigned value.
Animal.color = 'blue';
console.log(Animal.color, Dog.color);
```